# What does these few lines with tuple and list do? (c#)

Tags: c#, tuples

Can someone explain me how do these lines work?

```
public class TupleList<T1, T2> : List<Tuple<T1, T2>>                                                       
{
    public void Add(T1 item, T2 item2)                                                                           
    {
        this.Add(new Tuple<T1, T2>(item, item2));                                                       
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, which part do you not understand?

Comment: The explanation would depend heavily on your understanding of the individual parts of the class. Do you know what a [tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is? [Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)? [Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173149%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)?

Comment: If you don't understand *any* of it, then I'd recommend reading a good book or tutorial on C#. Just explaining this specific code isn't likely to help you nearly as much as learning about generics, inheritance etc in general terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom List derived from a list of tuples. The add method adds an entry to the List.Tuple is a pair of entries of any type. eg.

```
TupleList<string ,string> tl= new TupleList<string ,string>();
```

This initially has nothing in it.

```
{{  }}
```

now I call

```
tl.Add("Peter", "Adam") ;
```

This creates a Tuple using Peter and Adam as the Item1 and Item2 of the Tuple and then add this tuple to you TupleList.

```
TupleList tl now has :
{
    { "Peter", "Adam"}
}
```

if I do

```
tl.Add("abc","def"):
```

you will now store

```
{{ "Peter", "Adam"},{"abc","def"}}
```

Comment: argh.. i only have three lines of code and the rest is description. its not allowing me to submit it ..damn!!!

Comment: thank you very much for your quick and detailed answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a custom class that derives from a `List<Tuple<T1,T2>>` with `T1` and `T2` being type parameters.  You could use it like:

```
var list = new TupleList<int, int>();
list.Add(1,2);
```

Essentially it's just masking some of the extra code needed to work with a `List<Tuple<T1,T2>>`.

[Here's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x6a29h6.aspx) documentation on generics.  Any more than that you'll need to provide specific questions

Comment: Thank you for your help  :)